# Wireless Router: layer 3 or layer 2 switching?

Tags: router, switch, mac

I have a wireless router installed at my home (provided by ISP).
Scenario:

> Router IP: 192.168.1.1
>
> My Machine IP (X): 192.168.1.2
>
> IP of machine Y: 192.168.1.3

Now when I ping Y from my machine X.(ping 192.168.1.3 from 192.168.1.2)

```
My Routing table says: 

192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

This is a local route and now the ARP will be consulted for the MAC address of Y.
Suppose Y has mac: yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
Thus a packet will be sent out from wlan0 towards the router.

Now How will the router forward the packet? Will it switched based on MAC or Layer 3 IP lookup will be used to forward in the packet?

Comment: It likely is also an implementation detail, given tthat this is a router. It should work only on ARP - layer 2 - but who knows what some engineer in his wisdom has implemented.

Answer (score 1):

One would expect that because this involves only machines in the same network, the router will just act as a switch and look only at the MAC address. But routers in the real world don't always behave precisely the way you would expect.